# Is it len() function able to increase a for loop using enumerate() performance on python?

Tags: python

Have you already faced an increase of performance using len() before a for loop using enumerate?

I'm experiencing this, and I have no idea why is this happening, does someone have any idea?
The code gets some data from a database, store it into arrays `data_ids`, `dict_data`, `send_count`. After that, the data is prepared according a second database structure and inserted in groups of 100 datapoints. If I remove the calls `len(data_ids)` and `len(send_count)`, the execution of for loop gets really slow.

```
data_ids = [0,1,2,3,4,...,2500] #Example of data array
dict_data = [{'a':'0'},{'a':'1'}, {'a':'2'}, ..., {'a':'2'}]  #Example of data array
send_count = [1,3,5,6,7, ..., 0] #Exacly the same len of previous arrays
total = len(dict_data)
prepared_data = []
len(data_ids) #Removing those two, the code gets really slow
len(send_count)

num_to_get = 100
gotten= 0
to_send_data = []

if total <= num_to_get:
    num_to_get = total

for idx, data in enumerate(dict_data):
    print(f'{idx} of {total}\n')

    sent_count = send_count[idx]['send_count']
    data_id = data_ids[idx]['id']

    if sent_count > self.alert_sent_limit:
        print('There are many attempts to send this register without success, '
                            'please review the payload to fix the problem.')
        payload = json.dumps(data)

    prepared_data.append(prepare_data(data['data_object'],data_id))
    gotten = gotten + 1

    if gotten == num_to_get:
        ids_to_update, error_ids = insert_data_on_backend(prepared_data) #Insert data on second database
        ids_to_update = []
        prepared_data = []
        gotten = 0
```

Comment: You're going to need to make this a [mcve] since unless someone here can reproduce the issue, it's very unlikely anyone will be able to say what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

`len` has no side effects, so calling it will technically not improve performance. In fact, if you call `len` and ignore its return value, it will slightly decrease the performance since it's dead code. Here's some test:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'x = [1, 2, 3]' 'for i, v in enumerate(x): pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.365 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'x = [1, 2, 3]; len(x)' 'for i, v in enumerate(x): pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.39 usec per loop
```

The former doesn't call `len(x)` before calling `enumerate(x)` while the latter does.

Comment: An answer saying that these two lines don't make the program faster is not very useful, given that the OP claims to observe that deleting those two lines makes it slower. The problem is that the OP's issue is not reproducible, so there is not enough information to write an answer yet - you should wait for the question to be fixed before trying to answer.

Comment: @kaya3 The question is "Is it len() function able to increase a for loop using enumerate() performance on python?" and I'm answering *that*.

Comment: Then strictly, your answer is wrong, if we take the OP's claim at face value. For you to say this is an answer means you think the OP's claim is incorrect - i.e. you're saying the OP is wrong about their own observations of what happens when they run their own program - which is not impossible, but on what basis can you assume this?

Comment: For a trivial example, imagine writing a class with a custom `__len__` method which, when called, sets a flag telling some other part of the program to do something faster. So strictly speaking, calling `len` can have side-effects, because it can call an arbitrary class's `__len__` method which can do arbitrary things.

Comment: @kaya3 OP's using `len` directly on lists, and not in some custom class, that's why I said that calling it has no side effects. My answer is based on the code provided by OP and, as it is now, `len` is **not** causing any side effects. If OP updates the question, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: So what you're saying is, the code the OP posted is not sufficient to reproduce the issue the OP describes; that means the question "needs details or clarity" or is "missing debugging details". Those are reasons the question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @kaya3 It is a valid answer, since it answers the question in the title. If a future reader searches this question's title on Google and finds this question, they'll find an answer for it.

Comment: It's also, strictly speaking, a wrong answer, since it claims that what the OP claims to observe is impossible, and unless you have evidence that the OP did not actually observe it then we should take their word for it. Strictly, it is not impossible, because code without "side effects" can still have side-effects at a lower level, such as moving data from main memory to the CPU cache, as long as those side-effects do not violate the correct behaviour of the Python program according to the Python language specification (which does not specify anything about how fast programs should run).

Comment: @kaya3 The answer isn't saying that OP's observation is impossible, it's just saying that `len`, using the provided code, can't be the reason for it.

Comment: If `len` can't be the reason for it, then how can the OP's claim be correct: *"If I remove the calls len(data_ids) and len(send_count), the execution of for loop gets really slow."* ?

Comment: @kaya3 It can just be a coincidence, but my answer only refers to the question's title. If OP wants to be more specific and changes it to "Why **in my code** `len` is increasing performance?" then - just then - my answer will become invalid.

Comment: I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , particularly the section titled "answer well-asked questions". If you have to ignore the body text of a question and focus on just the title in order for the question to be answerable, then the question is not answerable. It is extremely normal for the title not to include all of the details necessary to understand what the question is actually asking, and intentionally ignoring the body text of a question almost guarantees that your answer will not be useful.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, my answer is certainly useful: it may help the OP to understand that `len` is not the reason for it in the general case and that it can be some other reason. I suggest you to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144452, particularly the accepted answer.